# Use GDB to Debug SIGTERM

Tags: gdb, sigterm

I have searched several questions on stackoverflow about debugging SIGTERM, but have not get the information I needed. Perhaps, I am still new to this issue.

My program terminated with the SIGTERM signal without core dump and I donot know how to track this down. My Question is, what is the general way of debugging this issue in GDB?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Although SIGTERM can be sent by the kernel in a few cases, it's almost always sent by another user process. If you run your program under gdb, then when it receives a SIGTERM it will become paused. You can then get some info about the signal by looking at the `$_siginfo` structure:

```
(gdb) print $_siginfo._sifields._kill
$2 = {si_pid = 3926, si_uid = 1001}
```

This is on Linux. It means that pid 3926 sent the signal, and the userid who sent it is 1001.

Answer (score 0):

> My program terminated with the SIGTERM signal without core dump

It is *expected* that if someone sends your program a `SIGTERM`, then no core dump is produced.

> and I donot know how to track this down.

You need to figure out where that `SIGTERM` is coming from. *Someone* sends it your program, and the key question is who.

Usually `SIGTERM` is sent when either <strike>you type Control-C in the terminal in which you started the program</strike> (correction, that would send `SIGINT`, not `SIGTERM`), or you type `kill <pid>` in some other terminal.

Comment: thank you, sir. I will figure out who sends me SIGTERM.